# KVM set gateway in isolated network

Tags: networking, kvm

I have a really annoying issue. I am using KVM on CentOS 7 and two networks.

- One of the networks is isolated with internal host routing only
- The other network is forwarding using NAT.

I have set up two VM's. One of the VM's is only connected to the isolated network and the other is connected to both.

VM #1 - Gateway (nat network and isolated network)
VM #2 - Isolated host (isolated network)

Now, the issue. I cannot get it VM #2 to be configured to use VM #1 as gateway with the network configuration. Sample below

```
<network>
  <name>isolated</name>
  <uuid>bbdafbfd-a73e-4a54-bc4d-2f060b571b71</uuid>
  <bridge name='virbr2' stp='on' delay='0'/>
  <mac address='52:54:00:46:53:61'/>
  <domain name='systems'/>
  <ip address='192.168.100.1' netmask='255.255.255.0'>
    <dhcp>
      <range start='192.168.100.128' end='192.168.100.254'/>
    </dhcp>
  </ip>
</network>
```

Do I have to manually configure that each time the VM boot if I want to use DHCP? I can solve it by setting static configuration but I don't really want to use that.

Cheers

Comment: If you want VM#2 to use DHCP you need to configure the VM accordingly.  But you haven't shown VM#2's network configuration. There's not much hope of anyone helping you as your question currently stands.

Comment: Well, the problem lies in the network configuration for the isolated network.  I want to be able to set the default gateway in the configuration above, and I cannot find how to do it. VM #2 is a standard Win 7 with DHCP enabled. It relies on what is configure din the network, as mentioned above. If I set it to be static it works fine. VM #1 has IP 192.168.100.250

Comment: Ah! I understand your problem now.  The default gateway (and DNS) is the IP address of the interface above (`192.168.100.1`).  I assume then, that your DHCP clients are either not being told this or choosing to ignore it. Have you used `tcpdump` or `wireshark` to see if it the gateway address is actually being sent by the host?

Comment: The IP above is the IP of the interface that is assigned by the virtual host. I want an entry such as gateway=192.168.100.250 that I can put somewhere in the settings so that the default gateway will be that inside the VM. But yes, you are correct. The gateway is not being sent, I have confirmed it.

Comment: Going by [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libvirt/+bug/247583), `libvirt` starts an instance of `dnsmasq` for each network, which cannot be configured.  The suggestion there is to not enable `dhcp` in the XML file (as you've done) and then start your own version of `dnsmasq` with your own custom configuration.

Comment: Yea, I've read that post as well. It was worth a try. I will do some testing with dnsmasq myself. Cheers anyways.

Answer (score 1):

As long as in your situation VM#1 is a gateway, it is intended to act as a DHCP server. So you just need to disable DHCP at network configuration xml (just remove anything between `<dhcp>` and `</dhcp>`) and run DHCP server or relay at VM#1.

I've just tested this approach and it works just fine for me.